# What's the difference between heavyset and heavy set?

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

Adjective: heavyset or heavy set? With or without a seperator?

E.g. a heavy set male, or a heavyset male?

Could I say a male is heavy set? (space included)

Comment: The answer depends on what you are trying to say. But you probably mean heavyset. Use of a dictionary would answer your question. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heavyset

Comment: 'Using a dictionary' can help but doesn't _fully_ 'answer your question' (unless, perhaps, that dictionary is the OED). Macmillan lists solely the hyphenated version of this compound adjective (for both what they call the 'American English definition' and the 'British English definition'). There are quite a few examples online of the open compound (in predicative usage), for instance in [this article from KMALand](http://www.kmaland.com/news/nebraska-city-bank-robbery-investigation-continues/article_d4237428-2d35-11e4-aada-0017a43b2370.html): ' "When I say he was heavy set," Lacey said ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The metal band's frontman was heavyset, and he played a heavy set."

Heavyset = fat

Heavy set != fat